# JSTL and Displaying the properties of each object

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

have search over Stackoverflow and found my code to be correct. However am getting an empty result for-each property. I have checked to see if my list is stored in the session, values are correctly stored, using version="3.0" in web.xml, and my jar's are in the lib folder. I might be missing something small but am not sure where to look. Any pointers will be nice.

My Code:

```
<%-- --%>
<c:foreach var="fixedLoan" items="${FixedLoans}">
    <tr>
        <td>${fixedLoan.id}</td>
        <td>${fixedLoan.name}</td>
        <td>${fixedLoan.ownerId}</td>
        <td>${fixedLoan.lenderId}</td>
        <td>${fixedLoan.date}</td>
        <td>${fixedLoan.amount}</td>
        <td>${fixedLoan.rate}</td>
        <td>${fixedLoan.yearsFixed}</td>
    </tr>
</c:foreach>
<%-- --%>
```

Results:

```
<c:foreach var="fixedLoan" items="[models.FixedLoan@3b74d21]">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: "Root JSP" is ambiguous. It must at least be in the very same JSP file as where you're using the tag. Problem symptoms still suggest otherwise and thus the duplicate still applies.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had the Prefix in a JSP page that included a JSP page that uses the Prefix. The Prefix need to be in the same JSP page. That I did not catch.